# I changed display name but it doesn't update in profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I changed profile name and save it then it doesn't reflect on current open page
[image]

[image]

I get an acknowledgement message also..I need to refresh but on save it didn't reflect on name. Is it bug or I'm missing something...

Comment: So you're saying it *did* update when you refreshed the page? I see you as Dhara now, if that's the new name.

Comment: yeah in profile editing ,after refreshing it updates not when I press save button @jonrsharpe why so? In general when you update your detail it needs to update at save time no need to refresh..isn't it?

Comment: It *could*, I'm not sure it *needs to*. You get a nice big confirmation of success, it's only one part of the page that lags, and in all likelihood your next action will be to navigate to some other page. Only the developers can tell you whether this is intentional, so I'll leave it for them.